Need single backslash in JSON response object ASP.NET Web API
Need a single backslash in JSON response using ASP.NET Web API. The following is the object that needed to be converted into JSON:
public RunTypeCanNotContainSpecialCharacters()
{
    SourceErrorCode = ApiExceptionCode.RunTypesErrorCodes.RunTypeCanNotContainSpecialCharacters;
    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
    ErrorCode =  ApiExceptionCode.RunTypesErrorCodes.RunTypeCanNotContainSpecialCharacters;
    Scenario =  "{The following special characters are not supported.[ '/', '#', '?', ',', '\']}";    
}

On object creation if I keep single slash then it gets omitted in the response, but on using more than one slash, it keeps that same number of backward slashes in the response object.
During debugging, I found out that during the last line of constructor execution i.e is for Scenario everything is happening i.e escaping of backslash literal.
I have tried using raw string i.e using @ but this add extra backslash in case of ASP.NET, but in console app it shows single backslash.
In response I want the following output specifically for userMessage:
"errors": 
[
    {
        "userMessage": "{The following special characters are not supported.[ '/', '#', '?', ',', '\']}",
        "errorCode": "RunTypesErrorCodes.RunTypeCanNotContainSpecialCharacters",
        "devMessage": "No error arguments available.",
        "moreInfo": null
    }
]

I tried many ways like JsonConvert.SerializeObject, Json.Encode and Regex.Unescape - but none are working.

The question is unclear. The JSON serializer will escape all strings as needed. You don't need to serialize string properties to JSON before serializing the entire object. If you want to include a backslash in a C# string just use "blah\\blah" or use @"blah\blah". They work.  The JSON you posted doesn't match the question's object either, so it's unclear what you want or what didn't work

it keeps that number of slashes in the response object. do you mean that blah\\blah appears the same in JSON? That's exactly what it should look like. JSON uses the same escaping as JavaScript and C#

Hi Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos for quick response. I have updated the question.
Yeah i need single backward slash in response object. Even tried with @ but it didnt worked out.

It did work. You already got a single backslash, that was escaped according to JSON rules. You can't have a single '' in JSON any more than you can have one in a C# or JavaScript string literal. It has to be escaped. The escape sequence is '\'. If you want to create the string The following special characters are not supported.[ '/', '#', '?', ',', '\'] you have to type var message="The following special characters are not supported.[ '/', '#', '?', ',', '\\']"; otherwise you'll get a compilation error. When printed, only a single backslash will appear.

If you serialize message you'll see the escaped sequence, as expected. Anyone that deserializes that string though will see a single string. That's no different than working with strings in C#. With the example above message.Contains(@"\") returns True while message.Contains(@"\\") returns False. There's only a single backslash

Yes when i try with @ in console application then it prints as required. Only issue occurs when i try with web api. Response contains double slash. It wont escape the literal.

The double slash is the escaped literal. That's why printing doesn't show double slashes. It seems there's no issue after all, just a misunderstanding of escape sequences
